# using windiff inside Perforce GUI tool

Tags: diff, perforce

Perforce diff tool is text based, instead windiff is much better. Is there a way to set windiff to be the default diff tool inside perforce?

Comment: Are you referring to p4v, or Perforce command line?  Or both?

Comment: I find the Perforce diff tool to be one of the best, especially for single files.  But to each their own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using P4V, go to Edit -> Preferences, and then to go the Diff tab. Pick the "Other application" radio button and then pick the program you want to use.

[image]